# New Data structure to store key value pairs

Tags: java, data-structures

I've a data set like below

```
attr1=val1  | attr2=val2  | attr3=val3  | attr4=val4  | attr5=val5,
attr1=val21 | attr2=val22 | attr3=val23 | attr4=val24 | attr5=val25,
attr1=val31 | attr2=val32 | attr3=val33 | attr4=val34 | attr5=val35,
```

key and value delimited by = and | (changed from space to avoid confusion) is delimiter for pairs. I can take care of parsing / tokenizing the input but my concern is in storing the data. 
I'm looking for a data structure (preferably in java) that can hold these **list of pairs in each row** in a key-value pair fashion.

Goals and Assumptions :

1. Input Key will be unique - there won't be any duplicate key, so
   hash code might be used in design if it helps constant lookups, no need to handle hash code
   collisions
2. Value should be accessible in constant time by passing key as input
3. No of pairs in a line is always same so no need to bother about dynamic re-  size of the data structure
4. we'll be accessing one row at time using key and get the
   corresponding value

Note :- I'm already aware of HashMap and its internal implementation in java. I'm just trying to avoid the structural overhead for this particular type of data set :)

The intent is to get the value of any attribute in a given row in a constant time by passing key.
I'll be dealing with ONLY ONE row at a time and I want to get the value of say attr1 in that row and if it's true do something. Hope this makes it clear.

I've only two ideas

1. Using HashMap is the most obvious solution
2. Having a list of
       Pair objects with key,value as instance variables and do a binary
       search in the sorted list which is O(logn) + some time for the
       equals check

   I'm looking if there's a better way than this :) Any ideas / thoughts on this ?

Comment: You realize this means your value can't contain a space, right?

Comment: yes.. my value won't have spaces in it

Comment: Your best bet is to use the `HashMap`. What overhead are you trying to avoid? There isn't really any as far as I am aware. Any current implementation for what you are needing is most likely using the `Map` interface, so an alternative is to implement it in your own class I suppose.

Comment: "there won't be any duplicate key, so hash code can be used in design, no need to handle hash code collisions" - you do realize that non-duplicate keys can still have hash collisions, right? It's not clear what you mean by "the structural overhead" of HashMap... have you *tried* using HashMap and found it too costly in some way?

Comment: Any of the standard Map implementations that might do for you?

Comment: Does each line contain attr1 - attr5, or does each line contain 5 different attributes?  In other words, are the attributes unique, or do you have 5 attributes with different values?

Comment: Well I guess you could actually have spaces, you'd just have to split on the last space before the next = sign, and require no spaces in key names.

Comment: While I completely agree with what the others have said ("Go for `HashMap`!"), there are different implementations of the same data structure among many libraries. And they usually try to avoid the "overhead" of creating `Entry` objects. For primitives, this is significant (with the addition of autoboxing!). You can take a look at imlpementations by Goldman-Sachs collections, fastutil, Trove, HPPC, Koloboke, maybe go off-heap with Chronicle-Map.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. yes i'm aware that 2 strings with different characters can have the same hash code but in my case hash code will always be unique because the string has chars and unique ID in it. I did try HashMap and found that there's is some overhead, for example a hashmap of 10000 entries, 320kb is for maintaining the hashmap structure. This is in a very critical part of my application and I wan't it scale as much as possible :)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, yes each line contains attr1-attr20. So 20 attributes with 20 values in each line. just like our html tags

Comment: @Arkantos: Your logic doesn't follow "the string has chars and a unique ID in it" doesn't mean that there won't be any hash collisions. You're seeing an "overhead" of 32 bytes per entry... that seems reasonable to me. How are you expecting to do better than that? For each entry, you need a key reference, a value reference, and the hash code, in an object. The *only* extra thing that HashMap.Entry has is a reference to the next entry in the chain.

Comment: @Slanec.. thanks. I'll have a look at them

Comment: @JonSkeet.. i don't understand the hashing issue. If u take three strings like attribute1, attribute2 and attribute3 they have different hashcodes 405645589 , 405645590 , 405645591. Like that we have 20 attributes, so if we're to create a structure to hold these 20 values, there won't be any hash collision rt ? Correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that the domain of keys is known and bounded? Can you enumerate all the 10000 possible keys and be sure there'll be no other possibilities?

Comment: yes. the no of keys is limited, as you can see in my question, only the values change in each row, keys remain same. Thats y i'm looking if we can use this to our advantage.

Comment: @Arkantos: Those three strings happen to have different hash codes - but "attribute12345" and "attribute98765" may not. Why would you want to *assume* that non-equal strings have non-equal hash codes, when that's clearly not always the case?

Comment: @JonSkeet.. i usually don't assume that non-equal strings have non-equal hashcodes, but i thought that the varying unique part of the string will make a difference. Thanks for clarifying it with an example :)

Comment: @Arkantos So, uh, um. If the key domain is known, would  `EnumMap` work?

Comment: @Slanec.. looks interesting. I almost forgot this one. Will do some testing and update on that. Thanks :)

Comment: whether the order of keys will be same i.e attr1 is the first key, attr2 is the second key, attr3 is the third key?

Answer (score 3):

What structural overhead? HashMap will give you the constant time lookups, you don't care about resizing, and plus you do not have to write/test the implementation as its already been done.

I've used HashMap in dozens of applications and unless you are dealing with massive scale I don't see any reason for you to roll your own implementation or go searching for another.

I should add as well that using common structures makes your code more accessible to others. Most Java developers understand the SDK HashMap implementations and its trade-offs. If they come across your own implementation or some other libraries implementation, they will have to go through the process of re-learning what the structure is and what the trade off's are.

Comment: I understand that using well known data structure makes it easy to maintain but in my current application, they're already using HashMap, we're just trying to optimize it because we'll be creating millions of maps. So we're just trying to refine the structure because that is where we have most control and data can be unbounded

Comment: @Arkantos what do you mean by millions of maps? Millions of maps in memory at a time? This has a smell of bad design if its the case. Or if you just mean that you handle millions of requests and a map is created per request and only lives in the scope of that request, that is common and not something you should necessarily optimize.

Comment: yes... thousands of request which have atleast 10k or more of these data sets, so at any given point of time, if you consider the peak load, we will find millions of such maps.

Comment: @Arkantos do you mean that each request will have 10K or more key / value pairs or 10K or more sets of key / value pairs

Comment: @Arkantos after reading the entire conversation here, I highly recommend you stop looking for a solution in this vein. It obviously does not result in a scaleable solution. It's time to question your design. Take a step back, think outside the box, and figure out how to solve the problem in a different way.

Comment: @gknicker.. Appreciate your concern but unfortunately we don't get to change so much as its a legacy application, all we can do is tinker a bit :)

Comment: @Arkantos even if that is the case, you are asking the wrong question. We don't even know what you are doing with this data, and why you even need to store it in a Hashmap. That would be  a better place to start.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is find a value by using a key in list of key-value pairs. I've only two ideas 

(1) Using HashMap is the most obvious solution
(2) Having a list of Pair objects with key,value as instance variables and do a binary search in the sorted list which is O(logn) + some time for the equals check 

I'm looking if there's a better way than this :)

Comment: @Arkantos Your still not asking the right question. Your dealing with major design decisions but only are giving hints at your problem here. For instance, what value are you searching for and why do you need that value? If you are determined to get an answer on SO than please update your question to include more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your keys are always the same, the most efficient solution is to create classes to represent each type of data.

```
public class Type1 {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    // etc
}
```

If for some reason you cannot represent the data types as classes, use a `java.util.Map` implementation with fixed keys, such as `java.util.EnumMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will be known set of keys and keys in each row will be in same order. If it is not in same order, while parsing and creating the data structure, please place it in the same order.
[image]